# Execute pytest via pyinstaller created exe extension file

Tags: python, pytest, pyinstaller

I had made more than 1 pytest test files I needed it to be convert them to a single exe file

1. I used pyinstaller for that not able to convert the test cases to .exe file
2. Even though if some how I will convert it I could not run it via clicking on .exe file as on console I am running it by python -m pytest

So Please help me guys

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. `pytest` needs to be able to analyze the Python source code and there isn't any inside the executable. The only reason to wrap a Python program in an `.exe` is so that you can deploy it to platforms that don't or can't have Python installed. If you are running tests, that is clearly in a development environment. Run the tests in your deployment pipeline *before* creating the executable.

Comment: Like I just want to create an exe file of the automation test code which I created via selenium pytest  so that I just have to export just the exe file to get my job done. So is there any way I can accomplish that.

Comment: I don't understand why your test process has to be an `.exe`, or why you think that is desirable. You (or your management) have chosen to work in Python, which is not a compiled language. That implies a certain way of working, such as having a pipeline that is able to run Python programs, not just `.exe`s. As I said upfront, I don't think what you want is possible. But maybe it is. If you persist, perhaps someone who understands the internals of `pytest` better than I do will consider this a sufficiently interesting technical challenge to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bat file rather, if you want to run it on a windows environment.
Keep the required libraries ( like pytest, selenium.. etc) in a requirements.txt file in root directory.
Keep the bat file with the root directory.
The commands in the bat file will go as below.

```
cd path/to/current/directory &
virtualenv env &
"cmd.exe" "\c .env/Scripts/Activte && pip install -r 
requirements.txt && pytes  your commands to trigger script 
here"
```

Once you hit the bat the dependent Libraries will be installed and later your scripts will trigger

Comment: Can you justify this with an example

Comment: lets assume we one requirements.txt file one test file in our project directory you can check further details about requrements.txt here https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-install-requirements/ .  follwoing will be the bat file content ```cd "%cd%" &
pip install virtualenv 
virtualenv venv &
"cmd.exe" "/c .\venv\Scripts\activate && pip install -r requirements.txt && pytest --driver chrome"```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to execute the exe file created by pyinstaller, that like on just clicking the exe file the exe will get execute based on the code mentioned just like on clicking the exe file the code should execute via python -m pytest

Comment: You should use the answer section to only send answers. If you want to ask a question, Update your existing question or create one :)